# Find certain points on circle when viewing from different point

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have a circle like this:

[image: 1]

Where there is a known line passing through the centre of the circle.

I want to find the points D and E on the image (left and right most part of the circle) when the circle is viewed from a different point, like this:

[image: 2]

Obviously points D and E are not the left and right most part of the circle (or rather, ellipse from this pov). Is there any way I can draw a line through the centre of the circle/ellipse that passes points D and E? I know a perpendicular line of line B-C passing through the centre (point A) will not work.

Is there maybe any relation between the angle of line B-C and the angle of the line that can be drawn between points D and E?

Comment: You should explain what you exactly mean by "viewed from a different point". Is that a perspective transformation? Or some kind of axonometry?

Comment: Another viewpoint in a 3D space. The circle itself is on the ground plane and is viewed from the top in the first image.